# rundeck s3 log plugin not loading logs to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, plugins, rundeck

we have included s3 log plugin by following steps in

https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/cluster/logstore/s3-log-storage-plugin.html

our **framework.properties** file look like below. authentication is through iam role hence access keys are not configured.

```
framework.plugin.ExecutionFileStorage.org.rundeck.amazon-s3.bucket=s3-bucket-for-rundeck

framework.plugin.ExecutionFileStorage.org.rundeck.amazon-s3.path=rundeck/logs/${job.project}/${job.execid}.log

framework.plugin.ExecutionFileStorage.org.rundeck.amazon-s3.region=us-east-1

framework.plugin.ExecutionFileStorage.org.rundeck.amazon-s3.forceSigV4=true
```

**plugin jar** copied to path:  `/var/lib/rundeck/libext/`

**rundeck-config.properties** file updated with below

```
rundeck.execution.logs.fileStoragePlugin=org.rundeck.amazon-s3
```

When we restart the rundeck service we do not see any logs in `service.log` file related to this plugin getting loaded nor any errors. below is what we see in log

```
2019-03-14 12:41:13.622  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : Starting Rundeck 3.0.17-20190311 (2019-03-11) ...
2019-03-14 12:41:13.632  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : using rdeck.base config property: /var/lib/rundeck
2019-03-14 12:41:13.654  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : loaded configuration: /etc/rundeck/framework.properties
2019-03-14 12:41:13.722  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : RSS feeds disabled
2019-03-14 12:41:13.722  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : Using jaas authentication
2019-03-14 12:41:13.731  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : Preauthentication is disabled
2019-03-14 12:41:13.849  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : Rundeck is ACTIVE: executions can be run.
2019-03-14 12:41:14.250  WARN --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : [Development Mode] Usage of H2 database is recommended only for development and testing
2019-03-14 12:41:14.343  INFO --- [           main] rundeckapp.BootStrap                     : Rundeck startup finished in 1071ms
```

No errors seen in `/var/log/rundeck/rundeck.log` as well, only below warning is seen

```
2019-03-14 15:47:54,027 [NodeService-SourceLoader1] WARN  com.dtolabs.rundeck.core.resources.DirectoryResourceModelSource - Not a directory: /home/rundeck/projects/RundeckTestproject
```

One executing any jobs, the logs are not getting pushed to s3 and not errors seen.

doubtful the s3 plugin is not getting loaded by rundeck. any inputs will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you download the plugin from here: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin/releases

And follow these instructions: https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin#install

Tip: Also, make sure that the plugins have the right permissions (user: rundeck, group: rundeck) to works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Its is working now. I also made another mistake which i corrected.  we were using different rundeck config property file custom defined and i included `fileStoragePlugin` in default config file which we corrected now.